# Convert DataFrame to Series

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = StringIO('2000-01-03,111.937502\n2000-01-04,102.500003\n2000-01-05,103.999997')
aapl = pd.read_csv(s, index_col = 0, parse_dates=True, header=None)
type(aapl)
```

I get `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. How can I convert this DataFrame to Series ?

Comment: No problem, I have closed it as it has been asked before. :)